# attempt to write a read-only database sqlite Wpf inno setup

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, inno-setup

I have created a windows application using SQLite database. The database file placed into the bin/Debug folder. I can successfully execute Read/Write commands using visual studio. But after installing the setup created using inno setup, I got error `attempt to write a read-only database`

How to solve this issue? any idea. this is from inno setup script

```
[Setup]
AppId={{7A32078B-4A69-4D03-ACD5-373283438A0C}
AppName=Test App
AppVersion=2.0.0
PrivilegesRequired=admin
DefaultDirName={pf}\test
DefaultGroupName=test
OutputDir=C:\Users\man\Desktop\2.0.0
OutputBaseFilename=test Setup
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\test.exe
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\test.exe"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,test}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

Comment: An application usually has no write permission in its installation folder. You should deploy the database file somewhere else, e.g. to [Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: Ok, But how to copy my DB to app data folder. they contain some prebuild data

Comment: You put it there with the installer.